# stackoverflow exception c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, stack, overflow

I am getting a stackoverflow exception when I try this code:

```
Thread Tcheck= new Thread(checkbr);
Tcheck.Start();

private void checkbr() 
{
    try
    {
        var RunningProcessPaths = ProcessFileNameFinderClass.GetAllRunningProcessFilePaths();
        if (RunningProcessPaths.Contains("chrome.exe"))
        {
            checkbr();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            // TO START NEW INSTANCE OF APP
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        checkbr();
    }
}
```

I want to know how to empty the physical memory of this app
because when I check my app in taskmanager I see it's increasing the memory used like crazy.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm just want to know if the browser opened or not and if it opened is it still opened or closed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is check if the process is running, you're better off having a `while` loop constantly running. This way you're not increasing the call stack each time.

```
private void checkbr() 
{
    try
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            var RunningProcessPaths = ProcessFileNameFinderClass.GetAllRunningProcessFilePaths();
            if (RunningProcessPaths.Contains("chrome.exe"))
            {   
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            else
            {             
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                // TO START NEW INSTANCE OF APP
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            }
        }            
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

This way, you're only doing something is the process *isn't* running, otherwise just wait for a few seconds and the loop will restart.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert of C# but it seems the method `checkbr()` calls itself recursively in case chrome is running.

This definitely causes a stack overflow.

Comment: yes i know that , but i don't know the best way to fix it and end loop and start it again clearly with fresh memory